# MySQL does not display during setup of Zabbix

Tags: mysql, apache, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, zabbix

I have issue during Zabbix 2.4-1 installation on ubuntu 14.04.
I used manual from [official site](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/installation/install_from_packages?s[]=ubuntu), installation was successful, no errors.
Next I created user 'zabbix' with all privileges and database 'zabbix' and imported schema.sql, images.sql and data.sql from Zabbix archive. Then I changed configuration files in /etc/zabbix dir:

### zabbix.conf.php

```
// Zabbix GUI configuration file
global $DB;

// Valid types are MYSQL, SQLITE3 or POSTGRESQL
$DB["TYPE"] = 'MYSQL';
$DB["SERVER"] = 'localhost';
$DB["PORT"] = '3306';

// SQLITE3 use full path to file/database: $DB["DATABASE"] = '/var/lib/zabbix/zabbix.sqlite3';
$DB["DATABASE"] = 'zabbix';
$DB["USER"] = 'zabbix';
$DB["PASSWORD"] = 'root';
// SCHEMA is relevant only for IBM_DB2 database
$DB["SCHEMA"] = '';

$ZBX_SERVER = 'localhost';
$ZBX_SERVER_PORT = '10051';
$ZBX_SERVER_NAME = '';

$IMAGE_FORMAT_DEFAULT = IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG;
```

### zabbix-server-mysql.conf

```
...
# dbc_dbtype: type of underlying database to use
# this exists primarily to let dbconfig-common know what database
# type to use when a package supports multiple database types.
# don't change this value unless you know for certain that this
# package supports multiple database types
dbc_dbtype='mysql'

# dbc_dbuser: database user
# the name of the user who we will use to connect to the database.
dbc_dbuser='zabbix'

# dbc_dbpass: database user password
# the password to use with the above username when connecting
# to a database, if one is required
dbc_dbpass='root'
...
```

I start it with apache server. When I go to localhost/zabbix I see Zabbix Installer. On step 3 it's necessary to configure DB connection. So, here is a problem:

[image: Trouble]

As you see, in select list is **only** PostgreSQL, so, I can't connect to database (mysql server is running) and go to the next step.

Comment: This worked for me in Zabbix version 4.4 on Debian Buster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PHP doesn't support MySQL at the moment. You need to install some `php-mysql*` package and then restart your webserver.

Comment: Thank you! `apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql` solved problem.

Comment: If postgresql is used, use `yum install php5-pgsql` or `yum install php56-php-pgsql` depends on the name on your platform. Then postgresql will be shown up in the dialog

Answer (score 3):

Your php package for mysql is not there so that it will not show while zabbix setup installation

install php-mysql package to resolve this error

```
#apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

and then restart apache

```
#systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing Zabbix 4.0 on Ub
So I ran

> apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
>
> sudo service apache2 restart

it works for me